# How to fetch data of NSString from array of structure hold by NSMutableArray in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have one NSMutableArray `tempArray = \[NSMutableArray array\];` which contains an array of structured objects with multiple data: `brand_package_id , slide_master_id etc....`

I want to sort out the tempArray according to `slide_master_id`'s.
Please see given image and help me to sort this problem.

[image: tempArray]

Comment: Use a for loop: `for (SliderMasterData *aSliderMasterData in tempArray) { NSString *name = [aSlideMasterData slide_name]; }`?

Comment: Is "sort out" the same as "filter"? Add your code to the question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NSSortDescriptor:

```
  NSSortDescriptor *slideDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
     initWithKey:@"slide_master_id" ascending:YES];
     NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[slideDescriptor];
 NSArray *sortedArray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```